# Enabling Istio in a namespacae

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

How should I enable istio injection as the side car in a namespace while creating the namespace yaml file itself ? I am doing it manually for now, what changes can I made in the yaml file.

Comment: You can find this information, and many more in [Istio Docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable Istio injection in the namespaces with setting `istio-injection=enabled` as a label while creating the namespace.

```
kind: Namespace
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    istio-injection: enabled
```

you can check the labels with `kubectl get ns --show-labels=true` command

```
[node2 ~]$ kubectl get ns --show-labels=true
NAME              STATUS   AGE     LABELS
default           Active   3m8s    <none>
kube-node-lease   Active   3m9s    <none>
kube-public       Active   3m9s    <none>
kube-system       Active   3m9s    <none>
test              Active   2m26s   istio-injection=enabled
```